# Initialize Bean after application start when external dependency is ready

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean that start some amqp consumers.

This bean is registered and initialized in the constructor of a `@Configuration` class like so:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext

...

ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).getBeanFactory();
beanFactory.registerSingleton(consumingIntegrationBeanName, consumingIntegration);
beanFactory.initializeBean(consumingIntegration, consumingIntegrationBeanName);
```

However the consumer process that is started when doing this, is dependant on an api that is starting simultaniously in a separate process.

I am thinking to do something like this:

```
while (!isInitialized) {
    Response response = httpClient.isAlive(http://api-in-separate-process/);
    if (response.status == 200) {
        beanFactory.initializeBean(consumingIntegration, consumingIntegrationBeanName);
        isInitialized = true;
    } else {
        wait 10
    }
}
```

But where would one place something like this? The rest of the application should not be affected by the delayed start of this specific bean.

Comment: why not use spring events and start the consumers after that the full spring context started by using a spring service?

Comment: When the context running the consumer is started i am not sure that the context running "api-in-separate-process" is also started.

Comment: I guess i need some kinda scheduled task that runs every 10 sec untill the beans have been initialized

Comment: Well you may generate a custom event when the  "api-in-separate-process" is started and put a listener on this event. When the listener gets this custom event it will start the consumer

Comment: How do you suggest i do that. I do not have control over which process begins first, so the "api-in-separate-process" could also be the one that finishes first.

Comment: Also they are in separate spring contexts. These events are local to one spring context right?

Comment: Well what I would do is the following thing: when the  "api-in-separate-process" is totally started I generate a kind of message (e.g. JMS message). In the other spring context (where the consumer should be started) I put a listener on the generated message (e.g. the JMS message in previous sentence). This listener starts consumers when it receives the message (e.g. the JMS message)

Comment: That sounds like a good solution, if you create an answer with this i will accept it.

Comment: Done.. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is the following thing: when the "api-in-separate-process" is totally started I generate a kind of message (e.g. JMS message). In the other spring context (where the consumer should be started) I put a listener on the generated message (e.g. the JMS message in previous sentence).

This listener starts consumers when it receives the message (e.g. the JMS message)

Angelo